# Wrong OAuth is validated in Swagger UI during Authorize

Tags: oauth-2.0, swagger-ui, openapi

In Swagger UI, when clicking the Authorize button for the client credentials type OAuth, required property validation is triggered for the Password type OAuth along with the client credentials OAuth.

[image]

Comment: Paste your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file into https://editor.swagger.io and make sure there are no syntax errors. If your file appears as valid, then it could be a Swagger UI bug, in this case open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Comment: On swagger editor, the issue is non replicable with the same yaml.

Comment: Also make sure you're using the latest version of Swagger UI, 3.40.0 (as of time of writing). To check your UI version, open the browser dev tools, switch to the Console tab and evaluate `versions`.

Comment: @Helen yes this is the latest version only.